# Search layer in MXDs

Tags: python, arcpy, symbology, layers, arcgis-10.3

I work on arcview 10.3 and i try to find layer called "ways" in several mxds. i try this code but it does not work. anyone know how to do it?:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxd
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "", df):
        if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue
        if lyr.symbologyType == "UNIQUE_VALUES":
            if lyr.name == "ways":
                print 'yes'
    mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: For future reference "it does not work" does not help people answer your question. Instead please provide more detailed information, such as "the following error occurred (copy/paste error message)" or "the code completed with no error message, but did not locate the layer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the path wrong for the line that reads:

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxd)
```

you have made the path a raw string, so the double backslash is wrong and making it fail, it should either be:

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\" + mxd)
```

or:

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\Project\\" + mxd)
```